# Is it possible to update the same field in same object for multiple updates in the same batch class

Tags: batch, governorlimits, field-update

Please let me know is it best practice to update the same field with different status for the same object in same batch class

```
  global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<SObject> scope) {
        List<TimeSheetEntry> tseListS = new List<TimeSheetEntry>();
        List<TimeSheetEntry> tseList = new List<TimeSheetEntry>();
        for(SObject s : scope){
            TimeSheetEntry tse = (TimeSheetEntry) s;
            if(tse.status == 'Approved'){
                tse.status = 'New'; 
            }
            update tse;
            tseListS.add(tse);
            if(tseListS.size() > 0 && tseListS[0].status != null && tseListS[0].status == 'New'){
                tse.status = 'Approved'; 
            }
            update tse;
            tseList.add(tse);
        }
```

Comment: Not sure why you're trying to do this, it looks like you're just setting all the records to 'Approved'. There's something wrong with your algorithm. As a side note, do not perform DML in a loop. That is "never" the right answer (there are rare exceptions, but this is not one of them).

Comment: Requirement is 'Status' is 'Approved'  records should pick through query and then changed to 'New' and then again change to 'Approved'.So, I need to update the same record two times. Is it the right way to written using best practices. Please confirm.

Comment: That requirement makes no sense. Something else in your org is likely designed in a way that is not optimal and it would likely be better in the long run to correct whatever automation that is rather than writing this batch class.

Comment: We are updating the data through data loader and instead of that, now using batch process. When we got a failed records through  integration and will take those records and then processing again from starting.

Answer (score 1):

That is an odd requirement.
First I'll start analysing a bit your code (adding comments to it)

```java
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<SObject> scope) {
        List<TimeSheetEntry> tseListS = new List<TimeSheetEntry>();
        // I don't really know why you need two lists
        List<TimeSheetEntry> tseList = new List<TimeSheetEntry>();
        for(SObject s : scope){
            TimeSheetEntry tse = (TimeSheetEntry) s;
            if(tse.status == 'Approved'){
                tse.status = 'New'; 
            }
            // It is a bad practice to do a DML inside a loop
            update tse;

            // Add element inside tseListS (it is outside the if, so you always add it) 
            tseListS.add(tse);
            // of course .size is > 0. You just added an element!
            // If inside your scope you have more than one record, you will a always check for position 0
            // you don't need to check for != null and == New. If its 'New' it can't be null and the other way around. (as long as you don't do a .status.xxx, it won't throw a Null-Pointer exception
            if(tseListS.size() > 0 && tseListS[0].status != null && tseListS[0].status == 'New'){
                tse.status = 'Approved'; 
            }

            // Another dml inside the loop :S
            update tse;
            // Add to a different list (always) and is never used.
            tseList.add(tse);
        }
    }
```

I say it is a bad practice to do DMLs inside a loop. That is the general rule. If your system is not bulk friendly (aka. your triggers do not support handling more than one record at a time), you might be force to do it.

Nevertheless, I would recommend to make your batch Bulk-friendly and if needed, run it with 1 as batch-size, so you get used to code this way.

One possible suggestion would be to

```java
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<SObject> scope) {
        // Declare list of affected Time Sheet Entries 
        List<TimeSheetEntry> affectedTSE = new List<TimeSheetEntry>();

        // you could also do
        // for (TimeSheetEntry tse : (List<TimeSheetEntry>)scope) { // and remove the tse declaration on the next line
        for(SObject s : scope){
            TimeSheetEntry tse = (TimeSheetEntry) s;
            // If is approved
            if(tse.Status == 'Approved'){
                // change status to New
                tse.Status = 'New'; 
                // add record as "Affected"
                affectedTSE.add(tse);
            }
        }

        // update all affected Time Sheet Entries
        // (DML outside loop)
        // You can optionally check if its empty or not before executing the code below.
        // Salesforce won't count the DML if affectedTSE is empty, but it could be more efficient to check here to avoid the code that will execute from now on.
        update affectedTSE;

        // for all affected Time Sheet Entries, we need to roll them back.
        // (they are only in the list of affectedTSE if they had Status == Approved)
        for(TimeSheetEntry tse : affectedTSE) {
            // change status back to Approved
            tse.status = 'Approved'; 
        }

        // update again the list of affected Time Sheet Entries
        // (DML outside loop)
        update affectedTSE;
    }
```

If TimeSheetEntry is changing quite often, I'd recommend to query only for the Id on the scope and do a query to TimeSheetEntry inside the execute, to make sure you get the latest field values.

Furthermore, if you select way too many fields on the start query, you could end-up rolling back changes on fields done by the triggers on Status or other stuff. If that is case ...

```
                // Change
                tse.Status = 'New';
                affectedTSE.add(tse);
                // By
                affectedTSE.add(new TimeSheetEntry(Id = tse.Id, Status = 'New'));
```

By doing so, you are just "pushing" a change on the Status field.